# GetStream iOS native - How to update Client token after first initialization

Tags: ios, getstream-io

I'm looking for an API to update the Client.Config.token value for the GetStream Library on iOS. Seems like this token is the only way for the library to parse the `user_id` from the JWT, however it is only parsed at init time of the singleton, Client.shared.

What happens if we need to update the token if the user has logged out of one account and into a different account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question. For now, the shared Client doesn't support Token update, but you can use a not shared instance of the Client. So, when another user logged in you can create a new Client instance with another token instead of the existing one.

To finish an instance client setup you need to create the current user like this:

```swift
if let currentUserId = client.currentUserId {
    client.create(user: User(id: currentUserId)) { [weak client] result in
        client?.currentUser = try? result.get()
    }
}
```

We'll add a token update for the shared Client in future releases.

Comment: It seems like calling `createCurrentUser` an any instance of a Client just references the shared client to grab the current user Id, instead of a property on the new instance of Client.

Comment: You are right, in this way you have to use `create(user:)` client method. Please check my updated answer.